# Getting "code":404,"message":"Not Found" error while creating a wallet address in node js

Tags: eosio-code, wallet, create

Here is my node.js code as described [here](https://developers.eos.io/keosd/reference#create)

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

The response I'm getting is

`{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","error":{"code":0,"name":"exception","what":"unspecified","details":[]}}`

Comment: Have you started running `nodeos` on the IP address `http://127.0.0.1:8888`?

Comment: Hi @PhillipHamnett-EOS42, Thanks for your response. Yes nodeos is running.

Comment: You need to pass data for wallet name

Comment: Hi @Mr.Y, Can you tell me how to do that ? Because I'm new to EOS

Comment: You need to add data field in options variable for example see this  curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/create   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '"mywallet"' . Relate this with your code. For quick response i have given curl example